# Excel offsetting macro increase performance by using Variant instead of Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro which checks if in column A is a cell containing "F" and then from column CC checks the last used row (I hope I got this right because just the CC column is the longest one)
If there is found an "F" then each cell on the right is moved down by two places. Worksheet has data from column A until IW

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "CC").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For Each rng In Range(Sheets(1).Range("A1"), Sheets(1).Range("A" & LastRow).End(xlUp))

If rng.Text = "F" Then
    rng.Offset(-1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    rng.Offset(-1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    rng.Offset(-1, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    rng.Offset(-1, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    rng.Offset(-1, 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    rng.Offset(-1, 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ...
    rng.Offset(-1, 256).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    rng.Offset(-1, 256).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End If
Next rng
Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE
```

Unfortunately for large data when I got 750+ rows this macro is terribly slow, with processing time going up to 90 minutes even in a Dual Xeon Processor (dual-core each of processors) with 16GB RAM machine.
I have tried to do performance optimizations like turning off screen updating, all the Excel worksheet has NO relative formulas, just data which should be moved down by two rows ...

After a lot of Googling, I found this page from Office Blogs, I notice that rather than offsetting a variant should be a lot more better in my case:

http://blogs.office.com/2008/10/03/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scan-a-large-range-in-excel/

I tried a few changes by declaring the `rng` as Variant instead of Range, but still same slow results.

Can you suggest me how should I change my code to use maybe the variant and achieve top performance?

Comment: Consider processing all data in arrays: operations that doesn't interact with sheets should allow you to increase performance drastically. Following this approach you should put data from sheet to 2-dimensional array by assigning `SomeRange.Value` to array. Then process the data, also you might create another one array having different size, and put result array back to the sheet by assigning it to `SomeRange.Value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For only 750 rows, looping with an array will make a negligible difference. What you are doing is individually inserting a 2 cells in each of 256 columns. Try inserting the entire row at once. I would also loop through the range in reverse. Also, your `.Insert` doesn't move down the current cell down, it moves the cell one above the current cell down. Please adjust as below.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow, i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "CC").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = LastRow to 1 Step -1
set rng = Cells(i,1)
If rng.Text = "F" Then
    Range("A" & i & ":" & "BZ" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftorAbove 
    Range("A" & i & ":" & "BZ" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftorAbove
    Range("CA" & i & ":" & "CI" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftorAbove 
    'rng.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    'rng.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End If
Next i
Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE
```

Comment: I have to apologize, I did not clearly mention that many columns need to go down two cells, but there are some on the left and on the right of column CC who need to move down just one cell. I am realigning data so we have everything in one row.

Comment: I would be glad to know maybe how may I add many cells at once down, so maybe from col.A to col.BZ I can move two rows down, then from col.CA to col.CI I may move the data just one row lower. This could bring some more performance maybe, what do you think for this case?

Comment: Please see my edited code. I commented out the two lines that inserted a new row for the entire row and added three lines that will move A:BZ down two line and CA:CI down one line.